# Selecting different blocks in vim

Tags: vim

Suppose I have the following text in  vim:-

```
aaaaaaaa        
bbbbbbbb    
ccccccccc    
ddddd   
eeeee       
ffffffffffffffff    
ggggg
```

I want to select lines 1,2,3,5 and 6 together...how can i do this?

Comment: Selections in vim are alwasy contiguous characters, lines or blocks. So you cannot select lines 3 and 5 without selecting line 4.

Comment: Besides, "selecting" is not very interesting. In Vim, think about results that you wish to have your file undergo, not editor actions you need to perform. What do you want to _do_ with those lines?

Comment: Actually i wanted to copy those lines.... It would be easier to copy multiple lines in a large file... If that was possible...

Comment: tell your final goal, after you selected those "blocks" what do you want to do with them

Comment: `gg"a3yy5G"A2yy` or `:1,3y a|5,6y A<CR>`. You can paste with `"ap` or `:pu a<CR>`. Consult `:help quotea`, `:help y`, `:help :y`. But typically you have more interesting text than `aaaaa bbbbb cc`. With Vim, meaning matters; there could be easier way to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take advantage of the [vim-multiple-cursors](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) plugin to do so.
Than you must define a pattern that fits to each line you want to mark. Type `<C-n>` (default mapping) jumps to the next match an mark it. Afterwards you can work on it, like for example change all at once with `c`, as usually.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to copy these lines to the clipboard:

```
:1,3 yank "+ | 5,6 yank "+
```

If you want to copy these lines to a specific place in your file, for example to the end of the file:

```
:1,3 t $ | 5,6 t $
```

If you need to move lines, use the :m instead of :t.

Compounding :Ex commands with "|" is efficient for large scale copies or moves and allows you to undo the entire action as one "edit."

Comment: The syntax of `:yank` does not include the quote, just the register name; so your code doesn't do what you want. In addition, if you do it without the quote, your second `:yank` will overwrite your first one. You can append to named registers as I did in my comment by uppercasing the register name; `"+` doesn't have that option. To repeat from my comment, the correct command with e.g. register `"a` would be `:1,3y a|5,6y A`

Answer (score 0):

You could perform a global action on that

Move all lines matching a pattern to end of file.

```
:g/\v([a-c]|[ef])/m$
```

Copy all lines matching a pattern to register 'a'.

```
:g/\v([a-c]|[ef])/y A
```

Uppercase them

```
 :g/\v([a-c]|[ef])/norm gUU
```

Comment: Note that the second one will append to whatever you had in `"a` before. Use `qaq` or `:let @a=""` to clear it beforehand.